# SQL to weekday instead of to_days?

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

I'm trying to make a change this part of the sql

```
(To_days( now( )) - TO_DAYS( o.date_payed)) days1,
(To_days( now( )) - TO_DAYS( o.date_purchased)) days2,
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to make two changes, the first one is that I would like to this be just `days1` and if the result of `To_days( now( )) - TO_DAYS( o.date_payed)` is empty use the second one.

The second change would be to instead of using `To_days` some way to use only weekdays, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question you can use [IF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), ie

```
SELECT IF((o.date_payed IS NOT NULL)&&(To_days(now()) != TO_DAYS(o.date_payed))
          ,To_days(now()) - TO_DAYS(o.date_payed)
          ,To_days(now()) - TO_DAYS(o.date_purchased)
        ) AS days1 ...
```

For the second part you can use the [date_format function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), ie `DATE_FORMAT(o.date_payed, '%w')`.